# Post to another python cgi-script from the current cgi-script

Tags: python, cgi

I have a python script called nav.py that loads pages. These pages have forms in them to post to other scripts that do the actual work. When I'm finished with these I would like to reload nav.py from inside the other scripts so that it takes the user back to the page they were just on. Is there a way to do this with the python cgi-module? The short version is I want to POST to another cgi-script from inside of the current cgi-script.

other.py -> POST -> nav.py

Comment: Why not just call functions from them?  It's all Python, right?

Comment: I wasn't able to use functions. I'm not sure if that's a limitation of cgi but every time I put a function into my scripts I got error messages when I tried to call the function. I'm looking to emulate submitting a form to a cgi-script from inside another cgi-script so it preserves the post data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way to do it but it works for my purposes. At the end of my script i just print a page with a form and hidden fields with my data just in case the javascript is slow and it tries to render the page before the javascript submits the form.

```
print("Content-Type: text/html\n\n")
print("""<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
 <form name='success' action='nav.py' method='post'>
     <input type='hidden' name='linkB' value='Add Assets' />
 </form>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
     document.success.submit()
 </script>
 </body>""")
```